# Paypal doesn't send an answer to the return url

Tags: paypal

I have a strange problem, my paypal applications functions perfect with my  sandboxbusiness paypal account but if I use a different bussines account, paypal calls my return URL after payment but with no answer string.

no error, no problems during payment process, simply there's a blank answer string. I'm not using AUTO RETURN, the customer must click on the return back button after payment.

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using using to return data back to your page?  Are you using the variable "rm" or are you using PDT?  Your other account may not be set up the same way as your other one that is working.  If you are using PDT make sure that you have PDT setup the same on the other account and etc.